# AjaxComplete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on the Opera workaround for printing IFrame. Now we all know that the only way to print an Iframe is to open it in a new window and then print it. The issue that I am facing is that when my IFrame is opened in a new window a series of ajax calls are triggered and I want to open the print window when all the ajax calls are completed. I searched a bit and found the global callback event ajaxComplete. I have my code something like this:

```
if($.browser.opera){
            var href = $("iframe:visible")[0].contentWindow.location.href;
            var printWindow = window.open(href, "printWindow", "scrollbars=yes");
            printWindow.onload = function(){
                $(this.document.getElementsByClassName("f-buttons")).hide();
                $(this.document.getElementsByClassName("f-progress")).hide();

            }
            $(printWindow.document.body).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ){
                printWindow.print();
            });
            $(printWindow).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ){
                printWindow.print();
            });


        }
```

I am not sure why the event is not getting triggered at first I tried it on the document as the documentation of ajaxComplete shows that it should only be attached to document but some people have suggested here that it can be attached on body too so I have tried this on body too but it is not getting initialized. Can anyone please tell me what am I missing on?

Comment: your problem is document.body it's execute all ajax  on that page.

Comment: @Mr.G -- Sorry I didn't get you.

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery docs, 1st:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached
>   to document.

and 2nd:

> If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to
>   false, the .ajaxComplete() method will not fire.

I don't see how are you calling the AJAX, but I can see that you are attaching the ajaxComplete method to the 'body' and not to the 'document' as the docs are saying.

Try these out and let me know what's happening.

Comment: True... I changed the ajaxComplete to ajaxStop since I want the printwindow to open after all ajax call complete. Now since $.ajax() needs the global option to be true which by default always still to be confirm I am calling a fake ajax call $.ajax({global:true}) under onload callback. It seems to work but I don't know whether to attach the ajaxStop to document or body. Which one is correct way?

Comment: Well, if you attached the ajaxComplete to the 'document' I'd say attach ajaxStop to the 'document' also.

Comment: I am facing another problem that is that onload is triggering before the handler is getting attached to the event callback. Can you give me the event that occurs at last...?